# Including break line in sed replacement

Tags: regex, bash, sed, newline

I've got the following sed replacement, which replaces an entire line with different text, if a certain string is found in the line.

```
sed "s/.*FOUNDSTRING.*/replacement \"text\" for line"/ test.txt
```

This works fine - but, for example I want to add a new line after 'for'. My initial thought was to try this:

```
sed "s/.*FOUNDSTRING.*/replacement \"text\" for \n line"/ test.txt
```

But this ends out replacing with the following:

```
replacement "text" for n line
```

Desired outcome:

```
replacement "text" for 
line
```

Comment: What version of sed is this with? What shell are you using? Are you sure you have the sed pattern quoted like that? I would expect this with an unquoted `\n` in the replacement (since the shell would strip it).

Comment: That should work, although your quoting could be a little better.

Comment: @EtanReisner The `\n` is quoted.

Comment: Not sure on the version of sed, it is on OS X Yosemite.
Using single quotations at the start and end of the command is yielding the same result.

Comment: Mac OS X comes with BSD sed, which cannot handle `\n` in replacement clauses. If you can depend on bash, you can use its `$''` C-style strings, i.e., `sed $'s/.*FOUNDSTRING.*/replacement "text" for \n line/'`

Comment: @Wintermute this caused on my machine: unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It needs to be `\\\n` (this ends up being a backslash directly followed by a newline).

Comment: That worked! Already selected an answer, but this works too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be painful to work with newlines in sed. There are also some differences in the behaviour depending on which version you're using. For simplicity and portability, I'd recommend using awk:

```
awk '{print /FOUNDSTRING/ ? "replacement \"text\" for\nline" : $0}' file
```

This prints the replacement string, newline included, if the pattern matches, otherwise prints the line `$0`.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
blah
blah FOUNDSTRING blah
blah
$ awk '{print /FOUNDSTRING/ ? "replacement \"text\" for\nline" : $0}' file
blah
replacement "text" for
line
blah
```

Of course there is more than one way to skin the cat, as shown in the comments:

```
awk '/FOUNDSTRING/ { $0 = "replacement \"text\" for \n line" } 1' file
```

This replaces the line `$0` with the new string when the pattern matches and uses the common shorthand `1` to print each line.

Comment: I'd suggest `awk '/FOUNDSTRING/ { $0 = "replacement \"text\" for \n line" } 1'`, but apart from style nitpicks, I agree that this is a sensible solution.